# Nested yield requests in Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, generator

I want to recursively crawl through 10 pages of reviews for beer_items I'm modeling on ratebeer.com. I want to collect all the reviews from these 10 pages (per specific beer) and associate the resulting text with an item. Here is my spider:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import FormRequest, Request
from beerscraping.items import BeerscrapingItem


class BeerSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'beerspider'
allowed_domains = ['www.ratebeer.com']
start_urls = ['http://www.ratebeer.com/search.php', ]

def parse(self, response):
    import string
    for c in ' ' + string.ascii_lowercase:
        formdata = {'BeerName': ' ',
                    'BeerStyles': '17',
                    'CountryID': '213',
                    'SortBy': '1'}
        formname = 'myform2'
        yield FormRequest.from_response(response,
                                        formname=formname,
                                        formdata=formdata,
                                        callback=self.parse_request)

def parse_request(self, response):
    xpath = "//td/span/a/@href"
    for link in response.xpath(xpath):
        url = 'http://www.ratebeer.com' + link.extract()
        request = Request(url, callback=self.parse_beer_data)
        request.meta['beer_id'] = url.split('/')[-2]  # Beer ID from URL
        yield request

def parse_name(self, data):
    result = data.extract()[0].split('(')[0]
    return result.strip("'")

def parse_abv(self, data):
    return data.extract()[-1]

def parse_rating(self, data):
    return data.extract()[0]

def parse_100_reviews(self, response):
    beer_item = BeerscrapingItem(response.meta['beer_item'])
    print "RESPONSE URL: ", response.url
    print "beer_item['keywords']:  ", beer_item['keywords']
    path_to_reviews = "//div[contains(@style, 'padding: 20px 10px 20px 0px')]/text()"
    for review in response.xpath(path_to_reviews):
        print "RESPONSE URL: ", response.url
        print "beer_item['keywords']: ", beer_item['keywords']
        beer_item['keywords'] += review.extract()
    page_no = int(response.url[-2])
    print "page_no: ", page_no
    if page_no < 3:  # If we haven't crawled over 10 pages of reviews yet
        print "DO WE ENTER THE LOOP????!?!?!?!"
        url = response.url[:-2] + str(page_no + 1) + '/'
        print "NEW URL: ", url
        request = Request(url, callback=self.parse_100_reviews)
        request.meta['beer_item'] = beer_item
        yield request

    yield beer_item

def parse_beer_data(self, response):
    path_to_name = "//div[contains(@class, 'user-header')]/h1/text()"
    path_to_brewery = "//big['Brewed By']/b/a/text()"
    path_to_abv = "//td/div/div/small/big/strong/text()"
    path_to_rating = "//div/span[contains(@itemprop, 'average')]/text()"

    beer_item = BeerscrapingItem()
    beer_item['id'] = response.meta['beer_id']
    beer_item['name'] = self.parse_name(response.xpath(path_to_name))
    beer_item['brewery'] = self.parse_name(response.xpath(path_to_brewery))
    beer_item['abv'] = self.parse_abv(response.xpath(path_to_abv))
    beer_item['rb_rating'] = self.parse_rating(response.xpath(path_to_rating))
    beer_item['keywords'] = ''
    request = Request(response.url + '1/1/', callback=self.parse_100_reviews)
    request.meta['beer_item'] = beer_item
    return request
```

So I create an item in parse_beer_data() and hand it to parse_100_reviews (10 on each page). The urls for the comments pages are in the form www.ratebeer.com/beer/(brand)/(brand_id)/1/(page_no)/ so I create a for-loop to iterate over 10 urls with (page_no) = 1, 2, ..., 10.
My spider shouldn't exit that loop until all 10 pages have been crawled, but that's not what happens.
Instead, the item is yielded after only one pass through the loop. I have all those print statements to verify that "page-no: 1" is the only page_no that gets printed.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the format of the code the same as it is in your script? And is the problem that the `parse_100_reviews` is `print`ing only `page_no: 1`? If both are answered with "yes" try to indent the code into the `loop`.

Comment: I've revised the parse_100_reviews function to just print out the response.urls and I've put it all in an if statement that checks the index of the comment page.

It appears to be crawling BFS as I get printed the first page of comments for every beer, then all of the second pages, third, and so on.

But the docs say that spiders crawl DFS so I would expect to see all 10 of the comments pages printed out for the first beer, then all 10 pages for the next beer and so on.

I need DFS so I can collect all reviews per beer before sending the Item thru the pipeline.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"else".

That's what the parse_100_reviews was missing.